# How to get AHCI support on an IDE Windows 7 installation?

Tags: windows-7, ahci

I installed Windows 7 onto a SSD with the motherboard in IDE mode. Now when I try to change the motherboard to AHCI mode, Windows 7 will not successfully boot (blue screens mid-boot).

How can I add AHCI support to the Windows 7 installation? If I can not add AHCI support I plan on doing a reinstall of Windows 7 with the motherboard in AHCI mode.

As a note, I just did the Windows 7 install yesterday, so I don't need to worry about losing any data on the hard drive due to reinstall.

Comment: Please rephrase your question. Right now you're asking for personal opinion and the question will probably be closed. You can edit it to ask what to do to take advantage of AHCI, not what you should do.

Comment: edits to hopefully reopen the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't have to reinstall Windows to enable AHCI. From [this Microsoft Support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922976):

> 1. Exit all Windows-based programs.
> 2. Click Start, type `regedit` in the Start Search box, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
>      If you receive the User Account Control dialog box, click Continue.
> 3. Locate and then click one of the following registry subkeys:
>      `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Msahci`
>      `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\IastorV`
> 4. In the pane on the right side, right-click Start in the Name column, and then click Modify.
>      In the Value data box, type 0, and then click OK.
>      On the File menu, click Exit to close Registry Editor.

Caution is necessary when mucking around in the registry. If you're uncomfortable with doing it yourself, Microsoft [also offers an automated "Fix-It" utility](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922976#MT3) to do it for you.

Comment: The Microsoft fix it patch works perfectly. A lot easier than doing the registry changes. For anyone who is interested here is the link to the Microsoft article describing the fix it http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922976

Comment: Many thanks for the quick help! I'd give you an upvote, but lack sufficient reputation.